# Gerrit hooks can't execute after a period of time

Tags: hook, gerrit

I have two gerrit hooks in `$review_site/hooks/patch-created` and `change-merged`.

Now, I found the two hooks can't execute sometimes, but I'm sure the permission are right and I can manually execute them.

When I restart the gerrit, the hooks can be executed.
I don't know if this because of my computer excessive Load?

The `$review_site/logs/error.log` outputs:

```
[2013-12-16 12:25:36,575] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits : 
Error computing patch of commit e5f70dc60231789312659d7b83964c4fcb3a573a
java.io.IOException: Failed to create ref refs/changes/13/8613/1 in data/git/repositories/mtk6572_cd/mtk6572_wimdata_ng/wcustores.git: REJECTED
at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits.createChange(ReceiveCommits.java:994)
at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits.createNewChanges(ReceiveCommits.java:887)
at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits.onPreReceive(ReceiveCommits.java:323)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceivePack.executeCommands(ReceivePack.java:1047)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceivePack.service(ReceivePack.java:697)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceivePack.receive(ReceivePack.java:617)
at com.google.gerrit.sshd.commands.Receive.runImpl(Receive.java:91)
at com.google.gerrit.sshd.AbstractGitCommand.service(AbstractGitCommand.java:103)
at com.google.gerrit.sshd.AbstractGitCommand.access$000(AbstractGitCommand.java:34)
at com.google.gerrit.sshd.AbstractGitCommand$1.run(AbstractGitCommand.java:69)
at com.google.gerrit.sshd.BaseCommand$TaskThunk.run(BaseCommand.java:397)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:333)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I do not know whether it is the cause.

Comment: Are you sure they don't execute or do they fail? If you replace the scripts with simply putting a timestamp in a file does that work?

Comment: Looks like your repo is broken?

Answer (score 0):

What's inside the `$review_site/logs/error_log` file? Do your hooks produce any output? This output would be logged there.